# I can't get my music bot in a discord voice channel (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Im making a discord bot to play music on my server and I can't put/call the bot for enter in a voice channel. I'm in the chat but everytime the bot keep saying "You must be in a voice channel to use the bot!" The code I use is this, it's not mine:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'play':
            
         function play (connection, message){
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

            server.queue.shift();

            server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                if(server.queue[0]){
                     play(connection, message);

                }else {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            });

        }

            if(!args[1]){
                message.channel.send("You need to provide a LINK!");
                return;
            }
           
            if(!message.member.voiceChannel){
                message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to use the bot!");
                return;
            }
            
            if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: []
            }
            
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);
            })

        break;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdzEw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `message.member.voiceChannel` you need to use `message.member.voice.channel`.

See the documentation about [Message.member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member), [GuildMember.voice](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice) and [VoiceState.channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel).

Comment: Ok, the bot finaly enter in the voice channel. I need to change everythin? Like !message.guild.voiceConnection to !message.guild.voice.connection and etc. Because the music dont play now the border goes green, but don't give any sound.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change it there as well.